# Skobbler Map crashes after returning from background

Tags: android, android-activity, skmaps

I am developing an application where I am using skobbler sdk 2.4 and I have encountered a problem when I open Map and then I go to background and open an app that needs a lot of memory like Clash of Clans :P.

After a few seconds when I return to the activity that contains the map it goes black and after 2 seconds it give this error to logcat:

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x44 in tid 27000 (GLThread 72284)
```

I have tried the same thing with the example that comes with the sdk and at first it crashes because it cant find String path that is kept inside application instance. I have made a workaround for this problem and fixed the null exception crash coming from application class `DemoApplication`. This wasnt a problem. The problem is with the map.

After this I went at the same point, I had the same problem even with the example app. The maps crashes and it cant initialize itself again after activity has been in background.

Any suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: we are not aware of any such issues, can you send us at dev@skobbler.com your demo project? On which devices have you tested?

Comment: I am working with lg g3 D855 (Android 5.0). Tomorrow I will send you an email with my demo project.

Comment: I found the solution of my problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to SylviA while I was checking my sample app I was trying to fix the problem of Null Pointer Exception and send it via email.

While I was writing the code for the second time I realized that I was doing something wrong and that was the reason of this absurd crash.

Here I am posting a part from the code where I have made my changes when map is initialized in `MapActivity.class`. These changes are made inside `DemoUtils.class`

```
/**
 * Initializes the SKMaps framework
 */
public static void initializeLibrary(final Context context) {
    final DemoApplication app = (DemoApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
    // get object holding map initialization settings
    SKMapsInitSettings initMapSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
    // set path to map resources and initial map style

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("map",0);
    if(app.getMapResourcesDirPath()==null) { // here happens the first error
        Toast.makeText(context,"Null Exception Error avoided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        app.setMapResourcesDirPath(mSharedPreferences.getString("map_path",null));
    }else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString("map_path",app.getMapResourcesDirPath());
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(app.getMapResourcesDirPath(),
            new SKMapViewStyle(app.getMapResourcesDirPath() + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
```

What I was doing wrong was at this line, and it was something like this:

```
initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(app.getMapResourcesDirPath(),
            new SKMapViewStyle( null + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
```

And it has to be done like this:

```
initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(app.getMapResourcesDirPath(),
            new SKMapViewStyle( app.getMapResourcesDirPath() + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
```

Thanks for your time :)